# '400 Bad Request' when post JSON in PostMan but working fine using curl despite setting Content-Type

Tags: json, flask, http-post, postman, http-status-code-400

I am having issues using postman to create the same post request that is working using curl.

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"datURL":"INSERT_BASE_64_HERE"}' http://localhost:5000/api
```

Here are my settings for postman and the error I get:

[image: Postman Screenshot]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Failed to decode JSON object: No JSON object could be decoded</p>
```

It is being caused by this line in my code, but I have set the Content-Type to application/json so not sure what could be causing it:

```
request.get_json(force = True)
```